# Чи можна поєднати прикметник короткий з прислівником завдовжки?

Tags: вживання-слів, прислівники

Чи можливе поєднання прикметників ***короткий, вузький, малий, тонкий*** з відповідними прислівниками ***завдовжки, завширшки, завбільшки та завтоншки***, коли я хочу описати виміри сполукою *завтовшки телефон тонкий* або *завширшки проїзд вузький*?
Розумію, що фрази *по товщині телефон тонкий* або *по ширині проїзд вузький* звучать звично, хоча не певний чи правильно.

СУМ дає приклади сполучуваності з точними та приблизними одиницями виміру (метр завдовжки або завдовжки з лікоть), а от сполучуваності з прикметниками немає.

Comment: *завдовжки* це те саме, що *довжиною* і неправильно казати *довжиною короткий* отже і *завдовжки короткий* не піде. Це може бути хіба для гуморески якоїсь.

Comment: уточніть, неправильно відповідно до якої норми? довжина - міра, короткий - слово, яким ми описуємо цю міру

Comment: Злітна смуга була цілих 100 метрів завдовжки, та виявилася занадто короткою для важкого російського бомбардувальника і він не злетів. Лід на річці майже 20 см завтовшки для російського панцирника виявився надто тонким і той пішов на дно.

Answer (score 1):

Зазвичай, слово *короткий* уже неявно містить у собі слово *довжина*, тобто, коли ми кажемо, що щось коротке, то ми маємо на увазі, що довжина цього предмета мала. Сказати *короткий завдовжки* це те саме, що сказати *маленької довжини завдовжки*. Не думаю, що існує правило, яке б це забороняло, але, НМД, така надлишковість невластива звичайній мові.

> [КОРОТКИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/korotkyj), а, е. 1. *Який має малу довжину; протилежне довгий. У садочок входить молодий хлопець в солом'яному брилі, в короткому синьому жупанку* (Шевч., II, 1953, 168); *Шия в його була така коротка, ніби голова лежала на самих плечах* (Н.-Лев., І, 1956, 117); *Обидві ноги його були прикуті до каменя залізними короткими ланцюгами* (Гончар, III, 1959, 108); ...

РЕД: Див. [плеоназм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC).

Comment: Це називається плеоназмом, що зазвичай є помилкою.

Comment: @oleedd дякую, почитав на вікі, цікаво.